# SharePoint 2013 search result is trimmed even user has access

Tags: search, sharepoint

I hope there's someone who can help me about SharePoint 2013 search.

One of my customer has an issue when searching a document by document id, the result is trimmed somehow.

Here are the things I have verified:

1. This user does have access to the document (He can open it directly by document URL)
2. Other users, like me, can search the document by doc id, such as xxx-12-23, without any problem
3. When the user search the document: docid:xxx-12-23, nothing returned

Does anyone had come across such issue before?